# ClassNotFoundException: if Android App downloaded from play store

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

Recently, I made an account in play store.My App were working good, if debugged from eclipse but when I download the same uploaded app from play store it crashes with following error:

> E/AndroidRuntime(13887): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   Didn't find class "android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable" on path:
>   DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.example-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]

**EDIT:** The problem were arising when application installed from APK.

Comment: What model device is crashing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$styleable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430551/noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v7-appcompat-rstyl)

Comment: @Piperoman It is oneplus one but the same app is working on it if debugged from eclipse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was including appcombat v7 in wrong way. A correct way is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10866431/android-activity-classnotfoundexception-tried-everything).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: The linked question/answer doesn't mention Google Play. Your apk worked in the first place, right?

Answer (score 1):

It seem a common problem in some devices, based in: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24809580/noclassdeffounderror-android-support-v7-internal-view-menu-menubuilder/26641388#26641388) you must try using:

```
keep class !android.support.v7.internal.view.menu.**,android.support.v7.** {*;}
```

instead:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.** {*;}
```

using proguard. More info in the link.

Comment: I will try your solution and let you inform if it works after uploading a new apk. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand how Proguard is related to this problem. We are talking about an APK that worked locally, but stopped working after being transformed (?) by Google Play, right?

Comment: The linked answer doesn't mention Google Play.