# Can't compile MediaRouteButton into project

Tags: chromecast, mediarouter

I'm doing in Movie project with CastButton, I completed a sample and this worked perfect. But when I'm doing in true project I have a problem.
I imported compile into my grande file, but when I create MediaRouteButton I have I got error, I tried many ways but I can't fix it, so I now I really need a help:
This is: compile file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-cast-framework:10.2.0'
```

this is logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v7/app/MediaRouteButton;
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.addMediaButton(MediaPlayerView.java:533)
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.access$4200(MediaPlayerView.java:53)
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView$3.run(MediaPlayerView.java:514)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5524)
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.preload(MediaPlayerView.java:490)
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.PlayerActivity.onResume(PlayerActivity.java:330)
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/jp.tsutayamovie-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/jp.tsutayamovie-1/lib/arm, /data/app/jp.tsutayamovie-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.addMediaButton(MediaPlayerView.java:533) 
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.access$4200(MediaPlayerView.java:53) 
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView$3.run(MediaPlayerView.java:514) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.runOnUiThread(Activity.java:5524) 
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.view.MediaPlayerView.preload(MediaPlayerView.java:490) 
                                                   at com.jlabs.pluginplayer.PlayerActivity.onResume(PlayerActivity.java:330) 
                                                   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1258) 
                                                   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:6327) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3092) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3134) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2481) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
                                                Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.app.MediaRouteButton
                                                   at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
                                                   at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                                                        ... 20 more
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430551/noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v7-appcompat-rstyl), you are getting that error because of the following reasons:

> In your gradle build file, maybe your app is targeting and compiling with the beta version of android that is still in development with:
>
> ```
> compileSdkVersion 'android-L'
> buildToolsVersion '20'
> ```
>
> as well as
>
> ```
> minSdkVersion 20
> targetSdkVersion 20
> ```
>
> First thing to note is that this app will not run correctly (at this time) on any device without android-L flashed to it.

Additional reference: [java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/v4/os/BuildCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39601370/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-failed-resolution-of-landroid-support-v4-os-bui)

> Check your classpath contains that jar (AppCompat), if your classpath doesn't contain the jar then just add that class in your classpath.

Hope this helps!

Comment: compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" 
minSdkVersion.apiLevel 18
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
I'm using it