# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: View::OnUnhandledKeyEventListener

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, kodein

I get following error log, but I can run my app.

```
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<androidx.core.view.ViewCompat$OnUnhandledKeyEventListenerWrapper>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/view/View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener;
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2560)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:658)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:801)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:741)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:874)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:835)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
...
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.view.View$OnUnhandledKeyEventListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/base.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_resources_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", 
                    zip file "/data/app/com.example.simplekodein-Vx1MPj54XnjYkszU0hkRBQ==/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", 
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:379)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void androidx.core.view.ViewCompat.setBackground(android.view.View, android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) (ViewCompat.java:2560)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarContainer.<init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (ActionBarContainer.java:62)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:-2)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(java.lang.Object[]) (Constructor.java:334)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:658)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:801)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(android.view.View, java.lang.String, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet) (LayoutInflater.java:741)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:874)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at void android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.View, android.util.AttributeSet, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:835)
com.example.simplekodein I/zygote64:     at android.view.View android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser, android.view.ViewGroup, boolean) (LayoutInflater.java:515)
...
```

I have two simple TextViews, but I can not see them, although I enter something into `textView.text= "dkjlkdsjf"`

**What am i missing?**

Comment: Check your Manifest file once and also to set text use `textView.setText`

Comment: @NovoLucas Ok, what shall I check the manifest for? I code in Kotlin, so I it is preferred to access  `.settext(s)` per `.text=s`

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/25432765/7337723

Comment: @NovoLucas Looks like this is not related, the stack trace is slightly different. Also, it happens not only on beta versions of Android

Comment: This issue could be related - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117685087